# Angular.js variable binding

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, angularjs, bind

I have simple `angular` web application and form on it. Form contains 2 `<input>` and 1 `<p>` elements. `p` value is `angular` template:

```
<p>{{status()}}</p>

$scope.status = function(){
    alert('p');
    return 'Some status';
}
```

When page loaded all displays normally i see alert and `'Some status'` in my `<p>`. But I have a question. When i try to input something to the `<input>`, i see `alert('p')` again and again every time when i typing any symbol to the `input`? Why?

Thank you.

Comment: Which `<input>` are you referring to?

Comment: I have just 2 `<input>` in forms, but they not in any way related to the p

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have an input with ng-model. When your input is modified, the model is changed. After each change, angular runs the digest, which reevaluates all the expressions in the view (technically it processes the watch list). You should read about it in the [Angular concepts in the Angular developer guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts).

Answer (score 2):

I think that you also have data binding on your input that's why angular is validating the scope each time you change something with key input and the alert is called because angular has to execute the function to check if the value returned is still the same.